# Show inf(U) = inf(T) - sup(S)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $T \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Suppose the S is bounded above and T is bounded below. Let $U = \{t-s|t \in T, s \in S \}$. Prove that U is bounded below and inf(U) = inf(T) - sup(S).

So, I found that both sup(s) and inf(T) exist because S is bounded above and T is bounded below. How can I show that U is bounded below? I'm not sure how to interpret the t-s in the set.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\forall x\in S,x\le \sup S\\\forall y\in T,y\ge \inf T$$therefore $$y-x\ge \inf T-\sup S$$

Answer (score 0):

As @Mostafa Ayaz showed:
$$\inf U \geqslant \inf T - \sup S$$
Now we must show the equality hold:
$$\inf T - \sup S < u \Longrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{1c}{\inf T < u + \sup S \\ \inf T - u < \sup S}\end{array} \right\} \Longrightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{1c}{ \exists t \in T: \inf T \leqslant t < u + \sup S \\ \exists s \in S:\inf T - u < s \leqslant \sup S}\end{array} \right\} \Longrightarrow$$
$$ \inf T - \sup S \leqslant t - s < u + (u - (\inf T - \sup S))$$
Since we can use any $u$ greater than $(\inf T - \sup S)$, so we can make it arbitrary close, therefore we have:
$$ \inf T - \sup S \leqslant t - s < \inf T - \sup S + \epsilon \qquad \forall\epsilon>0$$
The left inequality is actually what @Mostafa Ayaz showed, and the right one is what completes the proof. Because it shows that for every candidate greater than $(\inf T - \sup S)$, we have an element of $U$ that is lesser than it.